# Database Mirroring - Mixed SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

I am pretty sure what the answer is but I want to confirm this.
Is there a way to create mixed DB mirrors SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that yes, you can Mirror up to a [higher version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/upgrading-mirrored-instances), but you should really only do this if you're going to upgrade.

Once you fail over, you can't fail back down to a lower version.